# Publishing stuck to waiting for deployment

Tags: content-delivery, content-manager

i have configured 2013 sp1 into the environment. At the time of publishing my pages has got stuck into the publishing queue with "waiting for deployment status". I am not able to understand the problem. i have successfully transported the package but unable to deploy it.

Please find the cd_core.log file errors below

Retrieving list of files from location: {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test} with extension{.progress} 
2014-12-13 13:34:15,416 DEBUG HttpUpload - Retrieving list of files from location: {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test} with extension{.progress} 
2014-12-13 13:34:15,416 DEBUG HttpUpload - Found {0 } files in folder {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test}
2014-12-13 13:34:15,416 DEBUG HttpUpload - Found {0 } files in folder {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test}
2014-12-13 13:34:15,432 DEBUG HttpUpload - Retrieving list of files from location: {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test} with extension{.Content.zip} 
2014-12-13 13:34:15,432 DEBUG HttpUpload - Retrieving list of files from location: {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test} with extension{.Content.zip} 
2014-12-13 13:34:15,432 DEBUG HttpUpload - Found {21 } files in folder {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test}
2014-12-13 13:34:15,432 DEBUG HttpUpload - Found {21 } files in folder {C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test}
2014-12-13 13:34:15,463 INFO  HttpUpload - Received incoming file with name: tcm_0-189-66560.Content.zip
2014-12-13 13:34:15,463 INFO  HttpUpload - Received incoming file with name: tcm_0-189-66560.Content.zip
2014-12-13 13:34:15,463 DEBUG HttpUpload - Storing incoming file in destination: C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test\tcm_0-189-66560.Content.zip_tmp
2014-12-13 13:34:15,463 DEBUG HttpUpload - Storing incoming file in destination: C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test\tcm_0-189-66560.Content.zip_tmp
2014-12-13 13:34:15,463 DEBUG HttpUpload - Moving Tmp file to C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test\tcm_0-189-66560.Content.zip is successful.
2014-12-13 13:34:15,463 DEBUG HttpUpload - Moving Tmp file to C:\inetpub\Deployment_Test\tcm_0-189-66560.Content.zip is successful.
2014-12-13 13:34:19,009 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:19,009 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:24,042 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:24,042 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:29,084 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:29,084 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:34,106 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:34,106 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:39,122 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:39,122 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:44,155 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request
2014-12-13 13:34:44,155 DEBUG HttpUpload - transactionId parameter contained an invalid TCM URI string: meta.xml, processing as normal file request

Comment: adding to it I am also found this below error as well--------------------------ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'null' with schema 'schemas/cd_deployer_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'FileReceiver'. One of '{License, TCDLEngine, RMIChannel}' is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you found suggests your cd_deployer_conf.xml configuration file is invalid; could you post the contents of this file here (or better yet; try with the sample file provided by Tridion?)

Comment: I am similar issue. Only Tridion says publishing was successful. The publication transaction does not show up in the deployer log but the core log has have it with this error. Did a change to your deployer config fix this? I get this error randomly when I publish items. I then have to unpublish and republish to get the item to work. Thanks!

Comment: If you get the error sometimes but not always it is unlikely to be a configuration error as configuration applies always and not sometimes...

Comment: Thanks. This got me going in the right direction. It was a storage config issue. Two deployers were stepping on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for deployment usually means the Publishing Service finished rendering the content and it is trying to contact the Deployer to tell it to deploy the content.  The deployer is usually running as its' own website or sometimes configured to run as a Windows Service.  I would suggest to open the Publication Target and see the URL of the Deployer and try to connect to it from the CMS Publisher Server.